# How to Incoporate two input value sets to Apex:Map

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

I have the following issue. I have already mapped some Values(coming from a Search criteria) to apex:map. As per following code, lstAccount is output coming from a Search Criteria. .

```
<apex:map width="590px" height="300px" center="38.9047,77.0164" >
<apex:repeat value="{!lstAccount}" var="con">
 <apex:mapMarker title="{!con.Name}"
 position="{latitude:{!con.Location__Latitude__s},longitude:{!con.Location__Longitude__s}}">
 <apex:mapInfoWindow >
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-weight: bold;">
 <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!con.Name}"/>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
  <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!con.PersonMailingStreet}"/>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
  <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!con.PersonMailingCity},{!con.PersonMailingState}"/>
   </apex:outputPanel>
   <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
   <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!con.Phone}"/>
   </apex:outputPanel>
   </apex:mapInfoWindow>
```

Along with this, I have to perform another Search with the following SOQL. Its output is **Contact List**. How to incorporate this Contact List along with above **lstAccount** in the MAP.

```
String queryString =
       'SELECT Id, Name, PersonMailingStreet, PersonMailingCity, PersonMailingPostalCode , PersonMailingState, Donation_Request__c, Phone, Location__longitude__s, Location__latitude__s ' +'FROM Account' + 'WHERE RecordTypeId = :PersonAccRT and DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'mi\') < :miles ' + 'ORDER BY DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'mi\') ' +
       'LIMIT 10';

contacts = database.query(queryString);
```

Thanks Much In Advance

Reshmi

Comment: Is the existing list using the person accounts feature?

Comment: Yes Peter. Actually both the criteria using Person Account only. I have edited the code. There is no Contact object in picture(just the variable name is Contact). Sorry for the confusion!!  Thanks

Comment: I have not worked with person accounts, but I think you'll find that either 1) you can make a single query, 2) you can use one query to add to the existing list, or 3) you could use a wrapper class pattern to contain both. Not having an org to experiment with and lacking time this morning, I'm hesitant to offer an outright answer.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your time. Still I am not able to find a correct way :(